# counting unique values after counting unique rows?

Tags: sql

I'm pulling two columns from a table in order to return specific rows that have dates for current date, but the current date only. For example, say Pencils has dates 1/22/2014 and 2/22/2014. I don't want that to display, because it has two rows with unique dates. However, I'm having trouble counting the amount of unique rows after using     having count(*)>1     to get those unique rows. I tried counting the item and checking that against one (so if it only had one row, it would show), which 'worked', but then checked other values that didn't work.

```
  use db
  select todate, item
  from table
  group by todate, item
  having count(*)>1
  and cast(todate as date) = '2015-1-17'
  and count(item)=1
  order by item
```

As far as I can tell, that should work, shouldn't it? My guess is that the problem is in the count(item) and its' counting all the nonunique rows instead of just the unique rows, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Is there anyway to count only the unique rows?

Given this table,

```
todate        item       
2015-01-17    pencil
2015-01-17    pencil
2014-02-22    pencil
2015-01-17    pen
2015-01-17     pen   
2015-01-17    eraser
```

then it should return

```
 todate         item
 2015-01-17      pen
 2015-01-17      eraser
```

since those only have one unique date. It would not return pencil, since is has more than one unique date.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these two queries should work.  You can see which one performs better for you.
NOTE: if the `todate` column is already a date data type, or is a datetime where the time is always midnight, then do not cast as a date and it will perform better since it does not have to convert the data types.

```
select item, min(cast(todate as date)) as todate
from table
group by item
having min(cast(todate as date)) = '2015-1-17' --if you are wanting to filter for one date only
and min(cast(todate as date)) = max(cast(todate as date)) --all records have the same date
order by item
;

select item, min(cast(todate as date)) as todate
from table
group by item
having min(cast(todate as date)) = '2015-1-17' --if you are wanting to filter for one date only
and count(distinct cast(todate as date)) = 1 --this item has only one distinct date
order by item
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So my problem is that I should've been trying to count the distinct todate, instead of item?

Comment: There were a few problems. 1) you were grouping by todate, 2) you were checking for only items that had at least 2 records with count(*) > 1, so the eraser if you data example would not show, 3) you were counting the number of rows that had a non-null value for item with count(item) > 1